# How to create PDF by filling text with image pattern using PDF internal structure TR operator?

Tags: pdf, svg, pdf-generation

In one of my application they are creating PDF from SVG. To construct PDF they are constructing buffer as PDF internal structure tree( header, body,xref table,trailer etc). In SVG I have tspan element which has fill attribute with URl of image pattern.

In TR operator which rendering mode we need to use. TR has rendering modes with value from 0-7. Which rendering mode I need to use?
[image]

This is my svg file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg width="1260" height="828" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:lyb="http://www.myyear.com" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:se="http://svg-edit.googlecode.com" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <g>
    <title>Layer 1</title>
    <g>
      <g lyb:text-group="true" id="svg_rect4">
        <text>
          <tspan x="112" y="209" font-family="peergynt_regular" font-size="72" fill="transparent" fill-opacity="1" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="10" stroke-opacity="1" mask="url(#text5-0-0-0-stroke-mask)" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal">IMAGE</tspan><tspan x="112" y="209" font-family="peergynt_regular" font-size="72" fill="url(#1ca09741077648d4924d3c2995590c3d)" fill-opacity="1" stroke-linejoin="round" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal">IMAGE</tspan>
      </text>
      </g>
      <defs>
        <pattern id="1ca09741077648d4924d3c2995590c3d" height="369" width="551.7757009345794" x="109" y="132" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <image lyb:dropTargetClipPath="border_pattern6" lyb:srcId="pattern6" xlink:href="samsung_galaxy_note_20_ultra_02.JPEG" height="369" width="551.7757009345794" x="0" y="0" opacity="1"/>
        </pattern>
      </defs>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: @KJ,we will  leave about SVG, Generally to fill text with image which rendering mode needs to be used in TR operator?

Answer (score 1):

[In a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76913039/how-to-create-pdf-by-filling-text-with-image-pattern-using-pdf-internal-structur#comment135589117_76913039) you focus the question

> we will leave about SVG, Generally to fill text with image which rendering mode needs to be used in TR operator?

To fill text with an image you need to define a clip path while drawing a text. Thus, depending on whether you want your text only be filled with an image (or arbitrary content drawn later) or also filled and/or stroked in constant color, you need one of the modes 4 through 7:

[image]

*(ISO 32000-2, Table 104 — Text rendering modes)*

For example, for your text to only be filled with an image, use rendering mode 7 and draw the image after closing the text object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am very new to PDF internal structure. Could you please give some idea on how to draw image using PDF internal structure?

Comment: How to add pattern in pdf internal structure, what patterntype we need to set.

Comment: In PDF pattern structure, how to add image stream.

Comment: Indeed, that's a very wide subject. I would propose you have a look at the PDF specification and work with it. If you have not yet got a copy, look here: https://pdfa.org/resource/iso-32000-pdf/